# How can i delete items from Startup list

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 7, I was able to delete an item from startup list, using this

Registry path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig\startupreg
```

But on windows 10 there's no a such path. How can I do it?

Comment: You are correct, that key is not available in Windows 10. Do you mind using [Autoruns from Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) ?

Comment: You can disable apps through the Task Manager in the Startup tab.

Comment: Also, i found [this](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2944-startup-items-add-delete-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Sorry , but I don't want to disable . I want to delete so they don't appear anymore on Task Manager-Startup.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent registry keys for Windows 10 appear to be in subkeys within the following locations:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Explorer\StartupApproved` for system-wide startup items
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Explorer\StartupApproved` for per-user startup items

The subkeys are named `Run`, `Run32` and `StartupFolder` depending on what kind of startup item they correspond to (i.e. `HKxx\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key or shortcut in the "Startup" folder in the Start Menu).

The registry entries themselves have a binary value that starts with an even byte (`02`, `04`, `06`, etc.) followed by eleven zero bytes if the startup item is enabled, and an odd byte (`03`, `05`, `07`, etc.) followed by three zero bytes and eight seemingly random bytes if the startup item is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several registry keys you need, but:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

is definitely one of them at least!

Comment: Sorry , but I don't want to disable . I want to delete so they don't appear anymore on Task Manager-Startup. And on my pc , on the Run key I don't have any item , but on Task Manager-Startup I have items. I want something like the key that I have wrote above for the windows 7 where if I delete the item he doesn't show on Startup tab on msconfig.